# script to open newly added file in a folder automatically

Tags: python-3.x, bash

I have created client and server in python to transfer file within a network. but now I want a  script on server side that will run or open  received file automatically. so that on server side admin don't have to open the file .that received file will automatically open. so please
help me in this problem .
this client and server program is transfer all kind of file n all kind of format files like .mp3,mp4,ppt,.text etc but this all file should open open automatically

thank you

Comment: You need to specify what you mean by _open_, and what you mean by _newly_. Do you mean that you want to do something on files which have been added since the last time your checking program was running?

Comment: Possibly it will be easier to run command on remote server using remote ssh.
Watching on new files is not included in standard OS, so you have to use cron to scan directory on regular basis, or install incron which can monitor file system events.

Comment: I'm sure there's *no way* that such a behavior could be misused, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux OS use [inotify-tools](https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools) and then

```
inotifywait -q -m -r -e moved_to /watched/directory | \
        while read path change file; do
                /run/script-that-does-something-to-files.sh # and you can use path, file variables as arguments
        done
```